# Component doesn't pick up changes from vuex store

Tags: vue.js, vuex

https://codepen.io/bohdanafanasyev/pen/ZgqPWv?editors=1010

Above is the example of the issue I am facing now with the following logic:
1. Load records from firebase
2. Populate state with them
3. Render component that displays state

At this point, all work as expected.

4, Add a new product to the firebase
    4.1 On success add product to the state

In a console, we can see that commit has added the product, but the component itself doesn't pick up the change.

Can somebody please suggest what is missing in the logic above.

P.S: I will also appreciate if someone could leave their opinion on a better way to restore the namespaced module state rather then.

`Object.assign(state, newState)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two changes here to make the `cart` reactive:

1. Declare `cart` property in `cart/state`, so that in your store you have `state: {cart: {}}`;
2. In your `addProduct` mutation, change `state.cart[productName] = ""` to
   `Vue.set(state.cart, productName, "")`.

The takeaway is

1. always declare the property to make it reactive;
2. if you can't declare the property before hand, use `Vue.set` to add the property;

For more on [reactivity](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html).